# training gabbaim for Kri'at Hatorah

Tags: torah-reading, gabbai

I have been a Ba'al Kri'ah (Torah reader) for the past approx. 30 years. I try to be diligent about both word pronunciation and proper trope. There are several places where accenting the wrong syllable on the word changes its meaning (e.g - *Ve na TAT ti* = I gave vs. *Ve na ta TI* = I shall give). Likewise, there are numerous places where the worng trope can change the meaning of the verse.

Most gab'im know to correct the Torah reader when the word is incorrectly pronounced, except for the accenting shift as mentioned above. Few, if any, know to correct incorrect trope that changes the verse meaning.

Aren't there minimal requirements for being a gabbai for Torah reading? Is there an effective way to train people to become competent Gabba'im for performing this important job?

Comment: Having the Gabba'im learn the same way ba'alei koreh do would be a start.

Comment: So, you;re suggesting that Ba'ali Kri'ah should be "judged by their peers?"

Comment: Train them in Biblical Hebrew grammar? Im not really sure I understand your question...

Comment: @Dan I'm suggesting they should know the same grammar that you do.  Call it what you will.

Comment: Do you also want to be corrected for "homophones" (א/ע, ח/כ, כּ/ק, ...) and degēshim that change the meaning of the text?

Comment: hompohones would be difficult to detect. Can you give an example of dagesh that would change the meaning?

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this would be to make sure somebody diligent [and somewhat aggressive] is given a Tikkun/Chumash which highlights these things,  and have him correct you when needed. The **Simanim Tikun** comes to mind.

If you want as few corrections as possible, `highlight` those few instances that are critical in the Chumash/Tikun you give him.

Comment: +1 for the highlighting suggestion.  When I lein I give a marked-up printout to the gabbai where I've marked anything critical, which includes both "would change the meaning" and "for some reason I kept messing this one up in practice".

Comment: I REALLY like the highlighting suggestion! I may try it. I've never heard of "Simanim Tikun". Can you tell me who the author / publisher is and if I can locate this in any Jewish book store or online? Thanks

Comment: @Dan https://www.google.com/search?q=tikun+simanim

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is ask the *gabay rishon* (chief *gabay*) if the person standing on the other side of the *bima* (table) can be a person of your choosing instead of or in addition to the usual *gabay sheni* (vice-*gabay*; or instead of no one) and pick someone who you know knows grammar and will correct you. I've done this one the rare occasion that I was reading something I didn't know well (namely, when the scheduled reader did not show up and I was asked to [pinch-hit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pinch-hit)).

Comment: Tricky in my shul... I've had times when the gabbai incorrectly "corrected" me because he firgot to wear his glasses. Another one didn't adjust his hearing aid, properly!